# I want to upload media wordpress api with flutter

Tags: wordpress, api, flutter

I need to upload media wordpress api in flutter app, now I can upload media from wp api but the problem is the image after uploaded is broken and image size is very small, please help me

```js
var resposeimg = await http.post(
    'example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media', 
    body: jsonEncode({ 
        "file" : file.path.split("/").last, 
    }), 
    headers: { 
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
        "content-type" : "image/${imgformat.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'jpg'), 'jpeg')}", 
        'Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=${file.path.split("/").last}', 
        "Authorization": "Bearer ${widget.userToken}" 
    }
)
```

Comment: var resposeimg =
    await http.post('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
        body: jsonEncode({
          "file" : file.path.split("/").last,
        }),
        headers: {
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          "content-type" : "image/${imgformat.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'jpg'), 'jpeg')}",
          'Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=${file.path.split("/").last}',
          "Authorization": "Bearer ${widget.userToken}"
        })

Comment: this is my code